# Should we rename zoom tag to zoom-windows

Tags: discussion

There are so many posts in the suggested-edits review queue where users are constantly correcting these tags.  Mainly removing **zoom** and adding **zoom-meeting**.

My suggestion is to rename **zoom**  to **zoom-windows**  or **zoom-resize** to make it clearer.

Here is an [example](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/1175898)

Comment: zoom-resize sounds better, more descriptive, less likely for confusion with -windows

Comment: This is a fantastic example for this context [Is there a way to zoom in Zoom?](https://superuser.com/q/1739284/152004) tags [tag:zoom], [tag:zoom-meeting] :D